# Firestore golang issue with unmarshalling to proto type

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore, proto

i am trying to understand why the `DataTo()` method is not returning me all fields after passing the reference of struct in protobuf, but if i run almost same method `Data()` i am getting all

```golang
type Employee struct {
    StartDate   string 
    Id          string 
    Name        string
    Avatar      string
}
```

```golang
list, err := client.Collection(Company).Doc(user.CompanyID).Collection(Workers).Documents(ctx).GetAll()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err.Error())
        }
        values := make([]*pb.Employee, len(list))
        for i, v := range list {
            log.Println("By Data", &pb.Employee{
                StartDate: fmt.Sprint(b.Data()["startDate"]),
                Name:      b.Data()["name"].(string),
                Avatar:    b.Data()["avatar"].(string),
                Id:        b.Data()["id"].(string),
            })
            u := &pb.Employee{}
            b.DataTo(u)
            log.Println("by dataTo", u.StartDate, u.Name, u.Avatar, u.Id)
            values[i]= u
        }
log.Println(values)
```

Output:

```bash
By Data start_date:"2022-07-08 12:37:47.132904 +0000 UTC" id:"DILBuRmxVzVpOVG4iPuUeb8A4tN2" name:"alap" avatar:"https://image.com"
by dataTo    
By Data start_date:"2022-07-08 12:37:39.901286 +0000 UTC" id:"bH6wuk0ooCMKsh7RQqlGWtXhIZr1" name:"Jack" avatar:"https://image3.com"
by dataTo  Jack https://image3.com
[avatar:"https://image.com" name:"Jakub"  avatar:"https://image3.com"]
```

so as u could see above things are missing when trying to get document via `DataTo(p)` method. Anyone can see what i am doing wrong here ?

Regards.

Comment: As an approach, are you able to get just one document with the DataTo() method without the protobuf? [Check this example](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#example-DocumentSnapshot.DataTo) as a reference.

Comment: yes i am doing similar thing when adding an employee to the collection and it works, and then was thinking to list them same way ... so do not have to type all fields by hand

Comment: hmm hmm but ya still using actually proto that good way of thinking how i should test it .. ok let me test this with specifying struct

Answer (score 2):

its good practice for using

```
err := b.DataTo(&u)
if err != nil {
   fmt.Println(err)
}
```

maybe in your case, there is type data in the `struct` that didn't match with the schema in firestore.
if I could guess the `StartDate` field. if in the firestore schema it is a `timestamp` field, so you must set `time.Time` in your golang struct.